# Get last price from Comkort exchange PHP-JSON

Tags: php

Maybe Anybody can tell me why i got no output on my Browser with $mystring ?

http://pastebin.com/W0G4Sy4e

Shell Output : php test.php
0.01341011
0.01341011

I love using PHP!

Browser Output :
I love using PHP!

kindly regards
Jessy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to your web server php configuration that disallow you to open a remote url (see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488425/2652054 )